# php script is printed not executed

Tags: php, html, post, syntax-error

I have following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fancy Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content_login">
        <form method="post" action="app.php">
            <table>
                <thead>Please Login for more fancy Content!</thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my php script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        echo "Hello " . $_GET["username"];
    }
?>
```

Yeah simply nothing, but I only wanted to test, if a script would work when the Login Button is pressed. Surprise: It's not. I open index.html in my browser and the html part works properly, but if I press the Login Button the browser shows me this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        echo "Hello " . $_GET["username"];
    }
?>
```

I guess it's a syntax issue but I can't find it. Maybe you see it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you running under a server that support php?

Comment: Atm I am not using any server, just my browser. May this is the issue?

Comment: @Isabell Is it in localhost ?

Comment: I guess I need xampp then, don't I ?

Comment: PHP is server-side code - without a server, it won't execute. Newer versions do have a little in-built lightweight test server you can use if you don't want to go down the full Apache route : http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Yeah seams legit, and this is the reason why javascipt is working here, isn't it ? (js => client-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        if (!empty($username))
        {
            echo "hello $username";
        } else {
            echo "You must fill in the username!";
        }
    }
?>
```

To be honest, I would change index.html to index.php and place it into the top of that page so all errors etc are passed through one file.

Answer (score 1):

you should change that $_GET["username"] to $_POST["username"] variable to work it correctly

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        echo "Hello " . $_POST["username"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: but I don't want the value to be visible int the url

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the php code in app.php? If you have then you have not enabled mod_php in Apache. I would recommend you to use wampserver (on windows) since that takes care of the basic apache/php configuration.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

EDIT: You can not just execute your php code without having a webserver. Opening HTML files in your browser is client side and php is server side.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you don't have apache server running to make your PHP code works correctly.
And you are sending the data using POST no GET,  you must use the POST method to handle the data.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        echo "Hello " . $_POST["username"];
    }
?>
```